# changing the color of a custom drawing in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, drawing

So I've got a slider that changes the hue value of a UIColor. I want my custom drawing to have exactly this color.

My custom drawing class looks like this:

```
class CircleView: UIView {

    var color = UIColor().white {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), radius: bounds.height / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2*CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
            color.setFill()
            context.fillPath()
        }
    }

}
```

In my viewController, I have a property observer that should change the color of the circle, that my custom drawing class draws:

My properties:

```
private var hueValue: Float = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        color = UIColor(hue: CGFloat(hueValue), saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = color
        circle.color = color
    }
}
var color = UIColor()
var circle = CircleView()
```

And my Action method:

```
@IBAction func colorSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        hueValue = sender.value
}
```

The Action method changes the hue value which changes the color of the backgroundView. But it does not change the color of the circle. The circle stays white.

Any ideas?

Here is a Screenshot of the app:
[image]

Comment: Your approach looks like it should work. Try setting breakpoints in your action, in your `hueValue.didSet`, and in your `Circle.didSet` to see what's getting called.

Comment: Quick test using your code -- works fine for me. Are you correctly adding `circle` to your view? Is it possible you are inadvertently creating a 2nd instance?

Comment: as far as I can tell, debugging shows the correct behavior. Yes, I've added circle to my view. When I remove the `.white` color in the `CircleView` class in the variable `color`, the app crashes.

Comment: @WalterBeiter - show the code where you are adding `circle` to the view.

Comment: I did that in the storyboard. I assign the custom class `CircleView`to the view using the identity inspector

Comment: @WalterBeiter - hmmm... in the code you show, you are ***also*** creating a new instance of `circle` with the line: `var circle = CircleView()` ... what happens if you remove that line?

Comment: well I need that instance because I am setting it's color attribute in the `hueValue` didSet. If I remove that, I get an error, because `circle` is no longer declared. I dont have any other instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168127/discussion-between-donmag-and-walterbeiter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `UIView` added in your Storyboard, and you have set its Custom Class to `CircleView`, but you have **not** created an `@IBOutlet` connection to it, your code has no access to that view.

If you have `var circle = CircleView()` but you have not added **that** view to your view, nothing you change to `circle` will show up on screen.

In your storyboard, add your `UIView`, change its class to `CircleView`, and *then* ctrl-drag to create your `@IBOutlet`. Xcode will automatically set it to `@IBOutlet weak var circle: CircleView!`, and you can set its color (don't forget to remove the `var circle = CricleView()` line).